# Validate map keys in Firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How can I validate all keys in map in Firestore rules? Each key in map is an identifier related to a document.

Example:

User creates an invitation document with other documents access like this:

```
{
   "email": "foo@bar.com",
   "documents": {
      "document1": true,
      "document2": true,
      ...
   }
}
```

How can I check `document1` exists in database (ie. in `documents` collection)?

Comment: Please be more specific.  I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you saying there are any number of properties in an object called `documents` in this document, and you want to validate that every single one of them already exists somewhere else?

Comment: I have global collection `/documents` createad by multiple users. User can give an access to its own document to other users. In application user creates an invitation and selects some documents to be shared with other users. This invitation is saved in firestore (after that cloud functions sends email with invitation). I want to validate each documentId as key in documents map (JSON  above) that exists in `documents` collection and owned to that user.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write loops in security rules, so if you have an unknown number of documents to work with, you won't be able to validate them.  Instead, consider using Cloud Functions to check the values after it's been added, and delete the invitation if it's not valid.

Comment: What do you think about storing 'user documents ids' array as nested field in user document and using documents.keys().hasAny(path to user document.documents) feature?

Comment: You wouldn't be actually validating that the document exists.  For that to work, you'll have to make sure the list is always up to date with reality.

Comment: Sure, I would use Cloud Function to synchronize that field